# SQL get entities that have all values

Tags: sql

I cannot work out this syntax, but it does work (english: get MNAME's that have all PID).

Can anyone tell me why?

What would be an alternate syntax for achieve the same result?

**result:** *Sam*

```
SELECT MNAME
    FROM M
    WHERE NOT EXISTS
             ( SELECT *
               FROM P
               WHERE NOT EXISTS
                         ( SELECT *
                           FROM MP
                           WHERE MID = M.MID
                           AND PID = P.PID ) );
```

[image: database]

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT M.MID
FROM M
WHERE M.MID IN 
(SELECT MP.MID 
FROM MP 
GROUP BY MP.MID 
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM P))
```

Answer (score 1):

Please look up WikiPedia article "Relational Algebra", specifically "Division" in that article.  It is mindbending, I admit.  To the best of my knowledge and belief the solution you propose (multiple NOT EXISTS) is the only one that works for all cases (a classic relational division problem).

Strangely, a very similar question to this one came up on a different forum and I proposed the solution you show; the OP did not seem to believe me when I proposed this as the solution.

Wietze314's solution will work - for your datasets; not necessarily for all situations. As long as Sam has six (and only six) rows in table MP - irrespective of P1...P6 all being represented or not, then that solution will work.

Comment: Yes it is hard to get your head around. In the above example I am cannot execute the inner query alone and am not sure why. If I add the table name to it, `FROM MP, P, M` . The whole query gives the wrong answer. @Guest